# I've shared a parent account. The user can see the account, but not the children account. Can they view the children and their opportunities?

Tags: sharing

I've shared a parent account.  The user can see the account, but not the children account.  Can they view the children and their opportunities?

Also, I understand role heirarchy, but can the members of the same role see each other's accounts?

The error message is:

Insufficient Privileges
You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.

Answer (score 4):

whether members of the same role see each other's accounts, depends on the org wide default set for account object in Sharing Settings. If it is public then members of the same role should be able see each other's accounts.

If it is Private, then No. the owner of child accounts should either manually share the accounts or a sharing rule with proper criteria has to be built or some apex code should be written to explicitly code this.

If territory management is enabled then visibility depends on territories assigned. Yes it also depends on role hierarchy.

**You can check complete access to the account using the Sharing button on detail page. It should be visible to an admin. you might have to add it to layout if required.**

Access to Parent Account doesn't automatically grant access to child accounts. Although names of the account will be visible in Account Hierarchy page, clicking on account will result in error.